# Unhandled boost resolve call in Client class constructor

Tags: c++, boost, network-programming

I'm trying to create a Client class (UDP) using boost.  I'm attempting to turn the [short udp client tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime4.html) into a class that can handle the connection.  I'm not very familiar with network programming, boost, or catching errors.  I would appreciate an answer that addresses

- Why is the resolve function returning an unhandled exception? and
- How would I go about a proper check to handle the exception.

I've found a helpful TCPClient [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990840/boost-async-tcp-client) but some differences (I'm not even trying to do async client/server yet) makes it unhelpful to my problem.

Here is the code:

## Client class

```
class Client {
private:
    boost::asio::io_service* io;
    udp::resolver* res;
    udp::endpoint ep;
    std::string ip;
    udp::socket* sock;
    boost::system::error_code err;

public:
    Client(boost::asio::io_service& IO, std::string IP, std::string msg) : io(&IO) , ip(IP) ,
        res(new udp::resolver(IO)) , sock(new udp::socket(IO)) { 
            udp::resolver::query qry(udp::v4(), IP, msg);
            udp::resolver::iterator epit;
            ep = *res->resolve(qry); //unhandled exception here
        
    }
    ~Client() {
        delete res; delete sock; 
    }
    void Send(std::string & sbuf) {
        sock->open(udp::v4());
        sock->send_to(boost::asio::buffer(sbuf), ep);
    }
    void Listen() {
        std::array<char,128> rbuf;
        udp::endpoint sender_ep;
        size_t len = sock->receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(rbuf), sender_ep);
        std::cout.write(rbuf.data(),len);
    }
};
```

The program fails receives the unhandled exception in the constructor (as commented).  The exact error is

```
Unhandled exception at at 0x74C6C41F in Client.exe: Microsoft C++ exception:
boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<
boost::system::system_error> > at memory location 0x0022F278.
```

The main program is

```
int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    boost::system::error_code MyErr;

    Client Me(io,"127.0.0.1","MARCO");
    std::string msg = "MARCO";

    Me.Send(msg);
    Me.Listen();

    

    return 0;
}
```

I have already written and am running the server class in another program.  I think this is set up correctly but maybe it is part of the issue

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <array>
#include <boost\asio.hpp>
#include <string>

using boost::asio::ip::udp;

class Server {
private:

    boost::asio::io_service* io;
    udp::socket* sock;
    unsigned short port;
    
    std::array<char,1> rbuf;
    udp::endpoint rmtEP;
    boost::system::error_code err, ierr;

public:
    Server(boost::asio::io_service& IO, unsigned short PORT) : io(&IO) ,
        sock(new udp::socket(IO, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), PORT))) {}
    ~Server() { delete sock; }
    void Listen() {
        sock->receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(rbuf), rmtEP, 0, err);
        if(err && err != boost::asio::error::message_size)
            throw boost::system::system_error(err);
        
        sock->send_to(boost::asio::buffer("POLO"), rmtEP, 0, ierr);
    }

};


int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    boost::system::error_code MyErr;
    
    Server Host(io, 13);

        try{
            Host.Listen();
        }catch(std::exception &e) {
            std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
    

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should not below

> Client Me(io,"127.0.0.1","MARCO");

be

```
Client Me(io,"127.0.0.1","DAYTIME");
```

Because you are passing msg, to **query** and that argument should be actually service name instead of the message you want to send.

You can also see it from [boost daytime tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime4.html) as

```
udp::resolver::query query(udp::v4(), argv[1], "daytime");
```

Comment: I guess that was my bad.  I didn't even know what daytime meant.  Thought it was unrelated.  Thank you